# problem with homebrew installation path on linux

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, zsh, homebrew

So the problem looks like that :
I followed all the instructions from https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux , to install oh my posh via brew.

The problem is that I think I putted  a wrong path while copy pasting the instruction's code here :

*The installation script installs Homebrew to /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew using sudo if possible and within your home directory at ~/.linuxbrew otherwise. Homebrew does not use sudo after installation. Using /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew allows the use of more binary packages (bottles) than installing in your personal home directory.
The prefix /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew was chosen so that users without admin access can ask an admin to create a linuxbrew role account and still benefit from precompiled binaries. If you do not yourself have admin privileges, consider asking your admin staff to create a linuxbrew role account for you with home directory set to /home/linuxbrew.*

**Follow the Next steps instructions to add Homebrew to your PATH and to your bash shell profile script, either ~/.profile on Debian/Ubuntu or ~/.bash_profile on CentOS/Fedora/Red Hat.**

```
test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval "$(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
test -r ~/.bash_profile && echo "eval \"\$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)\"" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "eval \"\$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)\"" >> ~/.profile
```

And when i copy paste this piece of code it works on the actual terminal, but when i close the terminal and open again or open an other tab, and try the command "brew" again for example,  it says

```
zsh: command not found: brew
```

so for sure I messed up with some path directions.
I am not so good in linux, lets say maybe a junior intermediate level, but for this I am stuck, any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

`zsh` does not read `.bash_profile` nor `.profile`. You will either need to switch your shell to `bash`, or instead write the configuration to `.zprofile` which your shell `zsh` does read:

```
echo "eval \"\$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)\"" >> ~/.zprofile
```

Comment: when I paste this in the terminal it says " zsh: command not found: brew "

Comment: then you'll need to find where `brew` got installed to and use `/the/full/path/to/brew` or to add the `brew` directory to `PATH`

Comment: okay got it, can you maybe give me some tips to how find the full path? after some research yesterday I think it was in /etc/zsh and i have all these folders : newuser.zshrc.recommended           zlogin   zprofile           zshenv
newuser.zshrc.recommended.original  zlogout  zprofile.original  zshrc

Comment: "The installation script installs Homebrew to ..." so `brew` is probably under `bin` in one or the other of those installation directories, assuming those instructions were followed and the documentation is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution,

```
 echo "eval \"\$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)\"" >> ~/.zshrc
```

because of lack of knowledges i did it like that before :

`~ » echo "eval \"\$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)\"" >> ~/.profile`

so it was in .profile instead of .zshrc

Cheers

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the accepted answer, apart from writing to another file without reason.  The line should really be in `~/.zprofile`.